# Next Item in Plist Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Hey guys, i have a simple app just a load of images in one image view. Each is just included in a plist file and called when a cell is selected in popover window. All i want is a button with an action to get next item in plist and display in the image window. this sounds easy but i cant figure out the code to grab next item in plist? can anyone help cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the structure of your property list is, but I'm just going to guess that it's just a property list with one string containing the image name per row.  The easiest way to manage this is to just dump the plist file into an array like this:

```
// Load the data 
NSString *pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:someArrayNameString ofType:@"plist"];
self.someArrayYouCreated = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
```

then you can access the data in the array like this:

```
// load it into some string you created
nextImageNameString = [someArrayYouCreated objectAtIndex:nextImageNumberHere];
```

and then you can just use that string name as the next image to load.  So basically,

1. Dump plist into an array
2. Use `objectAtIndex` to access the images (remember, arrays start at index 0)